# rails Cannot nest nested form with parent form in index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**index.html.haml**

I have to display customer detail list in index page.I want the nested form 'goods address' fields also to be listed in index page

```html
%tbody
        - @customer_details.each do |customer|
          %tr
            %td= customer.customer_name
            %td= customer.customer_id
            %td= customer.address
            %td= customer.state
            %td= customer.email
              - customer.goods_address.each do |goods_address|
                %td= goods_address.delivery_address
                %td= goods_address.name
                %td= goods_address.address
                %td= goods_address.state
```

The problem is im getting undefined method 'each' for goods address. I dont know how to solve this. can someone help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be some of customer does not have `goods_address` so `each` can not performed on `nil` obect

Try:

```
%tbody
  - @customer_details.each do |customer|
    %tr
      %td= customer.customer_name
      %td= customer.customer_id
      %td= customer.address
      %td= customer.state
      %td= customer.email
        - if customer.goods_address.present?
          %td= customer.goods_address.delivery_address
          %td= customer.goods_address.name
          %td= customer.goods_address.address
          %td= customer.goods_address.state
```

Comment: I did.now getting error like undefined method `each' for #<GoodsAddress:0x0000000440bab0>

Comment: @HariPrakash: can you update your associations in your question?

Comment: class CustomerDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :goods_address

Comment: @HariPrakash: then you don't need to use `each` due to `has_one` relation, it will return you single object only

Comment: got it.Thank u very much